# Including markdown inside yaml front-matter

Tags: yaml, jekyll, github-pages

One of my web pages needs to include rows of items (image, title, description). The description must accept markdown. I haven't found any way to do this in Jekyll without plugins or creating multiple files, one for each item.

Another requirement is that the site be built by [Github Pages](http://pages.github.com/). ie: no Jekyll plugins, Redcarpet markdown.

Ideally, I would have liked to create a Jekyll data file (_data/products.yml) which contains a structure similar to below. Note that Description contains markdown list and formatting.

```
- Name: Company A
  Year: 2005
  Description: >
    I was responsible for the following:
    - Review of contracts
    - Hiring
    - Accounting

- Name: Company B
  Year: 2010
  Description: >
    My role included **supervising** the marketing team and leading **publicity**.
```

Another option I saw was to use Front-matter with the above info. It is slightly more cumbersome since it ties the data with a particular page (eg: work-experience.md).

I've tried various variations on the above but the formatting is never transformed into HTML. How can this be handled?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you do not wish to use Plugins, I believe the best bet is to have it in `_data` although not sure if it would be valid YAML or even a valid YAML is a requirement for _data content.

Have you tried using `markdownify` function such as

`{{ site.data.products.description | markdownify }}`

http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/

Comment: Yes, the markdownify filter works perfectly. There is no problem putting markdown as value for some YAML fields. I've been able to push to Github Pages and everything shows fine. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome advice, had never seen "markdownify" until now, works like a charm.

Comment: Hi! Can you please tell me how can I use this with assemble.io?